# Running a VB.NET webservice in .NET Core

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, vb.net-to-c#

I'm wondering what the best way to "Modernize" a VB.NET webservice is. I have a traditional webservice written using the `System.Web.Services.WebService` class in a old school website project.

`<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/JsonService.vb" Class="JsonService" %>`

Assuming I can break the webservice into it's "own thing/API" that doesn't have a front end coupled with it, I would like to be able to run this in AWS Lambda or Docker etc.

What would my options be? Some things I can think of:

- Re-write everything in C# in a .NET Core project
- Somehow use VB.NET and .NET Core/.NET 5 at the same time? (I don't know how to do this, I think .NET core only supports C#?)
- Use a "code converter" for the vb.net files, which the support seems pretty bad for at the moment.

I can read VB.NET code decently, but I am by no means an expert.

Comment: .NET Core/5 does support VB but not universally, e.g. you can create WinForms apps these days, but not web apps. You don't necessarily have to target .NET Core, as support for .NET Framework 4.8 will be around for a while yet. I'd suggest a Web API app, which is basically MVC without the V. If you target .NET Core/5 then it would have to be in C#, but you can put the bulk of the functionality in libraries, which could still be in VB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C# net5 web API project referencing a VB.NET net5 class library project, getting the VB to produce the value. You than thus leave most of the logic/objects in VB, and have the C# be a thin proxy for the logic. The debugger will step back and forth between c# and VB without complaint. You can gradually port over the VB if you want

[image]

ICSharpCode's VBNET converter is pretty good; gives a helpful start to any conversion at least. You'll learn the usual gotchas; VB using `()` for array indexers and methods, for example; converters don't always get that one right..